# Best Practices for Large Number of Entries

Tags: channel-entries, import

I have a database of  30,000+ government agencies and want to create a Channel Entry for each. My initial thought would be to create a Channel Field for all the data, then use an import extension to populate the Channel Fields.

I've never had to deal with large numbers of Channel Entries so I wonder if this is a sound approach or may there be another way.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a sound approach. Create a Channel for your your government agencies with the necessary Custom Fields to hold data. Then use a data import module to map the data to appropriate Channel Fields and import the records as Channel entries. There are two good add-ons for this: [DataGrab](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) and [Importer.](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/importer)

If you run into issues with running out of PHP memory and timing out you *may* need to break the import up into batches.

Comment: I'm very proficient with MySQL, is it possible to import directly to the db with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It's possible to use SQL to insert all the records, sure. You just need to make sure you hit all the necessary tables (at a minimum channel_titles and channel_data) and appropriate fields obviously. Another option is to use the [Channel Entries API](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using any type of export/import from MySQL, since you would have to manually make sure that foreign keys all match up properly. That would require a deep knowledge of EE's schema and would be error prone, or require scripting, the latter of which has already been done for you by the two add-ons linked in this answer.

Comment: I have done the import manually (and survived). Use the addons. ;)